# How to color series legend in highcharts when colorbypoint is set to true

Tags: highcharts

I am using highcharts and I have a column chart which has 2 data series', the first has each point with different coloured bars, the second series has all the same colour bars.

I understand that because I have set colorbypoint to true that its going to remove the colour swatch from the legend, but is there not a way to add one back in for the second series which is all 1 colour??

I have tried setting various options from the api including trying to add the colorbypoint to just the coloured series but that does not get applied. I have also tried to set colorbypoint to false on the plain series but that does not get applied either.

Is this even possible?

[image]

here is a link to a `fiddle` 
http://jsfiddle.net/wf_4/X4K4R/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just set `colorByPoint: false` for a second series, and set one color instead of colors array. See demo: http://jsfiddle.net/X4K4R/1/

```
$('#container').highcharts({

    chart: {
        type: 'column'
    },

    xAxis: {
        categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
    },

    plotOptions: {
        series: {
            colorByPoint: true
        }
    },

    series: [{
        data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]
    }, {
        colorByPoint: false,
        data: [54.4, 29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6],
        color: '#000000'
    }]
});
```

Comment: Thank you, actually, I noticed in your fiddle that you corrected something else which was stopping this from working for me... I had `colors: ['#000000']`, when you use `colors` and not `color`, that will prevent the legend color. :-)

Comment: It's in my answer ;) `and set one color instead of colors array.`

Comment: Oops. I really should take more time to read. Thank you @Pawel :-)